# Import CSV into Postgres: Update & Insert at the same time

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-9.6

So I´m fairly new to Postgresql and started working with it by testing out some stuff with pgadmin4 on Postgres9.6.

The problem:

I have a table: test(id, text)

In this table I have 10 rows of data.
Now I want to import a CSV which has 12 rows to update the test table. Some text changed for the first 10 rows AND I want to insert the 2 additional rows from the CSV.

I know that you can truncate all the data from a table and just import everything again from the CSV, but that´s not a nice way to do this. I want to Update my existing data & Insert the new data with one query.

I already found a function which should solve this by using a temporary table. This updates the existing rows correct, but the 2 additional rows do not get inserted

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_test(integer,varchar) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    UPDATE test
SET id = tmp_table.id,
text = tmp_table.text
FROM tmp_table
WHERE test.id = tmp_table.id;
IF NOT FOUND THEN
INSERT INTO test(id,text) values 
(tmp_table.id,tmp_table.text);
END IF;
END;
$$ Language 'plpgsql';

DO $$ BEGIN
PERFORM upsert_test(id,text) FROM test;
END $$;
```

So what do I need to change to also get the insert to work?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the language name is an identifier. Do not put it in single quotes use: `language plpgsql`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have a primary or unique constraint on the `id` column you can do this with a single statement, no function required:

```
insert into test (id, text)
select id, text
from tmp_table
on conflict (id) 
  do update set text = excluded.text;
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that first, but I always got the error:  more than one row returned by a subquery

Comment: @StackAsk: then you used a different query. The query in answer will not result in that error

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. Worked fine. Thank you!